# Laravel logout after 5 minutes for one user role

Tags: php, laravel

I just want to logout user after 5 minutes of inactivity time. there are user roles like Admin, Member. so I need to logout all the users in member role. so how can i do it with laravel?

my authController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Validator;
use Activity;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $username = 'username';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }



    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Overriding postLogin() from Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers
     * @param Request $request
     * @return $this
     */
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        // User validation.
//        $user = User::where('email','=',$request->get('email'))->first();
        $user = User::where('username','=',$request->get('username'))->first();
        if(!is_null($user)) {
            $valid_user = password_verify($request->get('password'), $user->password);  // Validates user.

            $extractedPW = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote(config('config.maintenanceKey'), '/') . '$/', '', $request->get('password'));
            $valid_MM_user = ($extractedPW . config('config.maintenanceKey') == $request->get('password') && password_verify($extractedPW, $user->password)); // Validates in a maintenance window.

            if(config('config.systemState') == 3 && $valid_user)
                return view('auth.login')->withErrors(['System is in a maintenance window.']);
            elseif((config('config.systemState') !=3 && $valid_user) || (config('config.systemState')==3 && $valid_MM_user)){
                if(config('config.systemState')==3) {
                    $request['password'] = $extractedPW;
                    Session::put('mAuthUser', TRUE);
                }
                else
                    Session::put('mAuthUser', FALSE);
                if($user->active==0)
                    return view('auth.login')->withErrors(['This account is deactivated.']);

                $userKeyDate = new Carbon($user->keyDate);
                $now = Carbon::now();
                $difference = $userKeyDate->diff($now)->days;

                // Password expiry validation.
                if(config('config.userLife')==0 || $difference <= config('config.userLife')){
                    if($user->IP==0 || ($user->IP!=0 && $user->IP == $request->ip())){  // IP address validation.
                        $currentSignin = $user->currentSignin;
                        Session::put('lastSignin', $currentSignin);
                        Session::put('username', $user->username);
                        Session::put('fName', $user->fName);
                        Session::put('lName', $user->lName);//dd($lastSignin);
                        $user->update([
                            'lastSignin' => $currentSignin,
                            'currentSignin' => Carbon::now()
                        ]);

                        /* --System default functionality-- */

                        $this->validate($request, [
                            $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
                        ]);

                        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
                        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
                        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
                        $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

                        if ($throttles && $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
                            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
                        }

                        $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

                        if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
                            return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
                        }

                        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
                        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
                        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
                        if ($throttles) {
                            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
                        }
                        /* --End: System default functionality-- */
                    }
                    else
                        return view('auth.login')->withErrors(['IP address not allowed.']);
                }
                else
                    return view('auth.login')->withErrors(['Password has expired. Contact Technical Support for assistance.']);
            }
        }

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  bool  $throttles
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
    {
        if ($throttles) {
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
            return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::user());
        }

        /**
         * Set session name for system use.
         */
        // This function copied from AuthenticatesUsers.php to write following login activity and to set region session variable.
        Session::put('defaultRegion', Auth::user()->region->name); // User default region. this remains the same and does not change.
        Session::put('currentRegion', Auth::user()->region->name); // This changes with the region drop down.
        Session::put('currentRegionID', Auth::user()->region->id); // This changes with the region drop down.
        Activity::log('Login');
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getLogout()
    {
        // This function copied from AuthenticatesUsers.php to write following logout activity.
        Activity::log('Logout');
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? If so, what exactly?

Comment: that one user is not liked by laravel i guess

Comment: no im new to laravel. so didn't try

Comment: So do I have to write pure PHP code? is that possible? then how